# Weird memory spikes in Debian VPS

Tags: linux, debian, apache-httpd, memory, nginx

I run a medium VPS (4GB RAM) as a web server. I host some private Ruby on Rails sites with Apache and mod_passenger. I also have two legacy apps which run with "passenger standalone" (two Nginx servers with passenger on ports 3000 and 4000). Apache acts as a proxy for those.

Most of the time this is works okay, but every few months the whole system goes berserk:

- RAM usage goes up to 100%
- the log files get filled with "Cannot allocate memory" & reverse proxy errors
- soon enough the whole system is unresponsive

Sometimes this clears up by itself, sometimes I have to ask my provider to reboot the system because I can't even SSH into it.

This *always* happens at night, when traffic is very low. Here are two graphs:

**Apache accesses**

[image]

**Memory consumption**

[image]

**How do I get to the bottom of this?** Which steps can I take to debug this situation? Is it possible that I have a bad neighbor on the machine?

Other processes on the major machine: MySQL, PostgreSQL, Elasticsearch, Redis

**UPDATE to clarify**

I'm looking for a tool that records processes with their memory & cpu consumption so I can track down the trouble maker(s). Is something like that out there or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: Probably a cron job. Check `/etc/cron.daily/` and `/etc/cron.d/`.

Comment: Yes, I had that suspicion too, but I found nothing out of the ordinary: MySQL dumper, munin, etc.

Comment: There doesn't have to be anything out of the ordinary, just that there is something wrong that causes those jobs to fail occasionally and do this. I also suspect the cron jobs for something that occurs always at the same time.

Comment: OK, assuming a cron job messes up - how do I find the culprit? — I've updated my question.

Comment: Start with a log of `ps` output. Run it every two seconds over night and see what's listed as the highest memory consumer(s). Once you figure out the offending process you can look deeper into it to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my personal experience of managing RoR apps, memory leaks can easily creep in and can catch you at most unexpected time. I would recommend doing two things to catch the culprit:

1. Use [sar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar) to record the system activities.
2. Since memory is specific target, use `free | grep "Mem:" | awk '{print $4}'` and send out a mail to yourself using `mailx` if the threshold exceeds a certain limit of your choice.

Usually there is a bad sql query or a rouge gem that cause this. If anything has recently changed with respect to these, then you may want to look into that as well.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know `sar`, I'll look into it. For now I'm dumping `ps` outputs into a file, but I will pick up your idea with `mailx`.